# Why is my jqPlot not rendering a canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot, html5boilerplate

I am trying to use jqPlot for a bar graph and I can't get it to show anything.

I have included the jqPlot code and all the plugins. I am not receiving any errors whatsoever

I have copied the example code directly:

html:

```
<div id="jqplot" class="plot">

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
"use strict";
(function ($){

        $.jqplot('jqplot',  [[[1, 2],[3,5.12],[5,13.1],[7,33.6],[9,85.9],[11,219.9]]]);

})(jQuery);
```

It is adding the class 'jqplot-target' to the 'jqplot' div so the javascript must be working, yet it is not adding a canvas/chart to the div, it displays just an empty div with the added class to it.

Any ideas why this is not rendering?

I am using html5boilerplate as well, but I can't find any known issues with the two of them.

Thanks,

Thomas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem. I had the main container div that the jqplot is inside set to display:none on page load and once you click the 'enter' button is shows with .fadeIn()

I suppose it can't add the canvas when the parent is display: none; - I've got it to work by calling the $.jqplot inside the function that fades in the main container after the user clicks enter...

Answer (score 2):

Can you show what your CSS is doing to the class "plot"? The [jqPlot Usage page](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html) says that you need to be sure to add width and height to the plot target.

Comment: I added width/height directly to #jqplot as well I've changed it to this <div id="jqplot" style="height:400px;width:300px;"></div> and it is still not rendering. When I do this in a blank page with no boilerplate it renders fine...

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've found the problem. See updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **replot** function on the generated chart, when you click on your button.

```
// create your chart
var plot1 = $.jqplot(...);

// hook the button press
$("button#enter").on("click", function(){
    // fade your tab in, wait for it to complete,
    $(".tab").fadeIn(1000, function(){
        // then replot, if not already drawn
        if(!plot1._drawCount){
            plot1.replot();
        }
    });
});
```

http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/hiddenPlotsInTabs.html

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue earlier, for some reason the following jqplot code wouldn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.jqplot('chart1', [[[1, 2], [3, 5.12], [5, 13.1], [7, 33.6], [9, 85.9], [11, 219.9]]]);
}
```

However, when I switched the $(document).ready(function{...} to jQuery(function ($){..} the jqplot code worked properly.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $.jqplot('chart1', [[[1, 2], [3, 5.12], [5, 13.1], [7, 33.6], [9, 85.9], [11, 219.9]]]);
}
```